# Is the Vue Instance / Component only the ViewModel in the MVVM?

Tags: vue.js, mvvm, vuejs2, vue-component

As from the [Vue Docs](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/#ViewModel):

> In Vue.js, every Vue instance is a ViewModel.

I am a little confused about that after reading so many articles on the design pattern like MVC, MVP, and MVVM.

We all know that in the Vue instance or Vue component (which is also a Vue instance), we have the `<template>`, which use HTML-based Syntax. **Is the  part not the View in MVVM?**

And there are `data()`, `computed` in Vue component. **Are they not the Model in MVVM?**

Below is the structure of a Vue SFC, which I divide into Model, View, and ViewModel. If there is anything wrong with it. Please help me to correct that and also help me understanding MVVM more while using an MVVM based JavaScript-Framework.

```
<template>
    <!-- the template part should be the View in MVVM since they don't contain any business logic but only the UI components. Which perfectly match the description of the View in MVVM.-->
</template>
<script>
export default = {
    data () {
        return {
            // the data should be the Model in MVVM, because they stand for their own and are the "actually" content of the app
        }
    },
    computed: {
        // computed properties should also be the Model in MVVM. When using vuex, I can, for example, get data with HTTP GET request through the vuex actions and parse the data, store it in the vuex store. When I need to use them, I get them from the computed in any child component I would like to.
    },
    methods: {
        // this should belong to the ViewModel in MVVM.
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
/* the style should be the View in MVVM. Because they are only responsible for how to present the data to the user.*/
</style>
```

And therefore, I think the `store.js` (used for vuex as a centralized state management) also belongs to the Model. Because it contains almost all of the business logic and saves the data we got from other API or from the user by itself.

So after all, when we read, a framework is base on MVVM or MVC or MVW (which Angular says: Model View Whatever). **What does it really mean and does it even matter for the actual web development?**

Comment: "Because it contains almost all of the business logic and saves the data we got from other API or from the user by itself."

Vuex is for application state management. You can very well have an application that does not have this requirement. It _can_ contain business logic sure, but that is not explicitly what it is for.

Answer (score 5):

I personally think for a basic vue instance you should't really read deep into design patterns.

When building big vue application, which involves multiples vuex state module and api layer. You can think about design pattern. But I feel it is still trivial for vue web applications. See below regarding some sort of answer(If I am wrong please correct me).

**template** - *View*

**data** & **vuex store states** - *Model*

**getters** & **computed** - *ViewModel*

**actions** & **apiLayer** - *ViewController*

**mutations** - *ViewController* -> *ViewModel*

*viewController* - When the view execute actions, which writes to the model. Like initiating a data fetch to the backend and populate the model with the fetched data.

Comment: Can you maybe explain more about what is ViewController? Because I have not read anything about it but I do have read a lot about the design pattern MVVM.

Comment: Where does `methods` belong to?

Comment: @AliN11 Methods is part of the ViewModel

Comment: I'd say `data` is ViewModel. Its properties can be consumed by `template` directly. Moreover, `data` is the right place for storing UI state. So it is not a Model accordingly to MVVM pattern.

Comment: VueX state is much more Model as it's a place for storing your application data. But it can also store a global UI state. In addition, VueX adds reactivity to the state, so that the state can be used inside components. So I think VueX state still cannot be fully treated as Model.