# Is Vuex the place to put validation rules?

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuex

I'm pretty new to Vuex, and I'm wondering whether to put my form validation rules, that must be checked when submit button is clicked, inside Vuex files (e.g. inside a getter) or not. Also the place to put respective error messages is not clear to me.

Any idea about that?

**Edit**

I want to ask my question in a more general way. In a medium to large web application, always there is some sort of data logic (or maybe business logic), that validation is one of the most common cases.

Recalling from MVC or MVVM architecture, the Model is the place to put these data and business logic, and if I was working on a MVC or MVVM project, I certainly put my validation logic inside the Model. So I want to know, are Vuex and other state management systems going to play a role similar to Model in MVC or MVVM? Should we decouple and move our data logic from components to Vuex?

I found a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726064/1919959), but I'm not sure about that being correct.

Comment: Do you want your state to be able to get into an "invalid" state or do you want it to always be in a "proper" state?  When does validation matter?  Only when submitting  data to an endpoint or at all times?  It depends on the use case.

Comment: @zero298 Yes, it is acceptable to go in an invalid state, and on click on submit button we will let the user know and will ask her to correct the entries to be able to proceed to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

I can share my approach to do that.

I have `constants` folder with `rules.js` file, which containts the following code:

```
export default {
  password: "min:2|max:32"
}
```

Then using `Vue.prototype.$rules` I share this object across all the application:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import rules from 'rules'
Vue.prototype.$rules = rules
```

Than I can use it with ease everywhere:

```
<template>
  <input-component :rules="$rules.password"></input-component>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    created() {
      console.log(this.$rules.password)
    }
  }
</script>
```

My team and I is satisfied with this approach.